# Remove n elements from array using start and end index

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have the following table in a Postgres database:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  id SERIAL NOT NULL,
  arr int[] NOT NULL
)
```

And the array contains about 500k elements.

I would like to know if there is an efficient way to update `arr` column by removing a set of elements from the array given the start and end index or just the number of "n first elements" to remove.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can [access](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING) individual elements or ranges of elements:

If you e.g. want to remove elements 5 to 8, you can do:

```
select arr[1:4]||arr[9:]
from test;
```

or as an update:

```
update test
   set arr = arr[1:4]||arr[9:];
```

To remove the "first n elements", just use the slice after the n+1 element, e.g. to get remove the first 5 elements:

```
select arr[6:]
from test;
```

The syntax `arr[6:]` requires Postgres 9.6 or later, for earlier versions you need

```
select arr[6:cardinality(arr)]
from test;
```

`cardinality()` was introduced in 9.4, if you are using an even older version, you need:

```
select arr[6:array_lengt(arr,1)]
from test;
```

Comment: Do you know if the mentioned  `update` will do a copy of the new slice? Because I need to do frequent removals on big arrays.

Comment: @saloua What do you mean with "copy of the new slice"? A column is always written completely (not in "pieces") if you are referring to that

Comment: I am asking  whether while updating the column value, there will be the original array content and the new content discarding the slice. Then, if the array is huge and I need parallel updates this will be inefficient.

Comment: If you want this to be more efficient, don't use an array, use a properly normalized one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 2):

You can use slices (see [8.15.3. Accessing Arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING)).

```
create table example 
as select array[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] arr;
```

Remove first 3 elements:

```
select arr[4:8]
from example;

     arr     
-------------
 {4,5,6,7,8}
(1 row)
```

Remove elements from 4 to 5:

```
select arr[1:3] || arr[6:8] as arr
from example;

      arr      
---------------
 {1,2,3,6,7,8}
(1 row)
```

Remove first 5 elements if the length of the array is unknown:

```
select arr[6:array_length(arr,1)]
from example;

   arr   
---------
 {6,7,8}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how efficient would be the update if the array is very big and I need to do the removal frequently.

Comment: I think it's the most efficient way to remove elements.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It is also not working for me in `psql` I am getting
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "]"

Comment: @saloua: which Postgres version are you using? This works for me: http://imgur.com/a/ZX1e1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.4`.

Comment: @saloua: ah, that was introduced in 9.6

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the info.